# Restlet with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: restlet, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Has anyone successfully deployed a Restlet application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

If so, are there any significant gotchas that need to be worked around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm it is working fine. There is an upcoming chapter 9 in "Restlet in Action" book that will describe it in detail. Basically, you can just use the Java EE edition of Restlet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Restlet works on Elastic Beanstalk. I wrote a [blog entry](http://tembrel.blogspot.com/2012/01/deploying-restlet-components-in-elastic.html) that contains sample code for a Restlet Component that runs both standalone (for development purposes) and in servlet mode (for Elastic Beanstalk). It deals with passing sensitive information via the fixed set of environment variables that Beanstalk supports, but using more informative names for your non-Beanstalk deployments.